# Nginx and Zend configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I've got an issue with my Zend Application. When I open http://ip-193-187-64-113.e24cloud.com/ there is only a blank page instead loaded layout. 
This is my nginx.conf (included in main nginx.conf)

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;

    error_log       /var/log/postgre.yourdomain.com_error.log error;

    root   /var/www/test/public;
    index  index.html index.php;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
       if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
           return 404;
       }

       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, nginx and postgresql, php 5.5

Thanks for help!

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in your PHP script but have PHP error display disabled. This is the default for PHP in Ubuntu.

You can enable them in your `php.ini` by searching the configuration option `display_errors` and setting it to `On`.

Alternatively, you can use the following PHP instruction to enable them from your code :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: The same PHP script files are working on my local machine. Moreover, on the server showing errors is enabled.

Comment: Try looking into nginx error logs. If there is a nginx related error, it should be displayed here.

You can also try to display a `phpinfo()` page, see it something change.

Comment: I cleared error.log, and after reloading nginx error.log file is empty

Comment: And the access log ? You can check there the state of your request, that would ensure that your request is correctly processed.

I don't know much about Zend, but maybe you don't display anything because there is nothing to display ?

Comment: Access.log doesn't contain anything what looks strange. In my opinion the problem is the nginx.conf but I don't know what can I repair and how.

Comment: If your phpinfo displays correctly, there is not much chances that the nginx.conf is wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily because I need redirection from all request to index.php file from /var/www/test/public but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Try adding `rewrite_log on;` into your configuration file then checking logs again.